# How to solve "The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected" on time machine

Tags: mac, time-machine, smb

When I use the time machine in the new macOS Sonoma to connect to my smb device, something goes wrong.

It says "The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected"

But I directly use Finder to connect to smb, it works normally.

Then I switched to a new Mac, which also has the Sonoma system and is connected to the same network. There is no problem connecting with Finder, but when using Time Machine, it also gives an error message. However, this time it is "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"

log 1:

```
2023-09-26 20:57:47  Failed to deserialize dictionary with name 'com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist' from disk image 'file:///Volumes/SSD1-1/Xun's%20Mac%20Studio%201.sparsebundle/', error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data}
2023-09-26 20:57:47  Failed to deserialize dictionary with name 'com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist' from disk image 'file:///Volumes/SSD1-1/Xun's%20Mac%20Studio%201.sparsebundle/', error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data}
2023-09-26 20:57:47  Diskimage '/Volumes/SSD1-1/Xun's Mac Studio 1.sparsebundle' with host UUID '(null)' and MAC address '(null)' did not match this computer
2023-09-26 20:57:48  Failed to read capabilities for '/Volumes/SSD1-1', error: Socket is not connected
2023-09-26 20:57:50  Unable to obtain disk for '/Volumes/SSD1-1'
2023-09-26 20:57:50  Reporting preparation error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
2023-09-26 20:58:08  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:58:31  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:58:51  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:59:47  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:59:51  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:59:58  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
```

log 2:

```
2023-09-26 20:52:46  Failed to deserialize dictionary with name 'com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist' from disk image 'file:///Volumes/SSD1-1/Xun's%20Mac%20Studio%201.sparsebundle/', error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data}
2023-09-26 20:52:46  Diskimage '/Volumes/SSD1-1/Xun's Mac Studio 1.sparsebundle' with host UUID '(null)' and MAC address '(null)' did not match this computer
2023-09-26 20:52:46  Failed to read capabilities for '/Volumes/SSD1-1', error: Socket is not connected
2023-09-26 20:52:49  Unable to obtain disk for '/Volumes/SSD1-1'
2023-09-26 20:52:49  Reporting preparation error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57 "Socket is not connected"
2023-09-26 20:53:03  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:53:26  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:53:37  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:53:54  TMPowerState: 2
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Skipping scheduled Time Machine backup: Automatic backups disabled
2023-09-26 20:53:54  fs_snapshot_list failed: Operation not supported
2023-09-26 20:53:54  fs_snapshot_list failed: Operation not supported
2023-09-26 20:53:54  fs_snapshot_list failed: Operation not supported
2023-09-26 20:53:54  fs_snapshot_list failed: Operation not supported
2023-09-26 20:53:54  fs_snapshot_list failed: Operation not supported
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Starting age based thinning of Time Machine local snapshots on disk '/'
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Starting age based thinning of Time Machine local snapshots on disk '/System/Volumes/Data'
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Starting age based thinning of Time Machine local snapshots on disk '/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1'
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Starting age based thinning of Time Machine local snapshots on disk '/System/Volumes/Update/SFR/mnt1'
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Failed to wait for snapshot deletion to complete on disk '/', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=30 "Read-only file system"
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Failed to wait for snapshot deletion to complete on disk '/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Age-based thinning deleted Time Machine snapshot 'com.apple.TimeMachine.2023-08-25-131039.local' on disk '/System/Volumes/Data
2023-09-26 20:53:54  Age-based thinning deleted Time Machine snapshot 'com.apple.TimeMachine.2023-09-01-172833.local' on disk '/System/Volumes/Data
2023-09-26 20:54:15  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:54:30  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:54:36  com.apple.backupd.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:54:45  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:54:52  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:55:34  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:55:37  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:55:56  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:56:07  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:56:38  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:56:44  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:57:13  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:57:29  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:57:43  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:58:03  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:58:23  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:58:37  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:58:47  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:59:34  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:59:47  Failed to read capabilities for '/Volumes/Share', error: Operation not permitted
2023-09-26 20:59:47  Failed to read capabilities for '/Volumes/PVE_Backup', error: Operation not permitted
2023-09-26 20:59:47  Failed to read capabilities for '/Volumes/SSD1', error: Operation not permitted
2023-09-26 20:59:51  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 20:59:53  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 21:00:10  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 21:00:55  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
2023-09-26 21:01:09  com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same problem and may have found a solution.

I was digging through my OSX keychain and I found the problem on my system. The "network password" used by TimeMachine was incorrect...but ONLY by the case of the first character.

TM MUST have used this password when I first ran the backup which was successful. Also, I don't recall TM asking for the password, so it must have used what Finder was using. I wonder if this a bug in Sonoma. IDK, but it was fixed by manually editing the entry in my case. Check your saved passwords in keychain.